# What is the state of a spinner when it's displaying a drop down list?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a spinner with a custom view, anyway I managed to show different drawables for when the spinner is inactive and also for when it's pressed, I would like to keep the pressed state drawable when the dropdown list shows. Here is mi XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ComboBoxInactive" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ComboBoxActive" />
  <item android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/ComboBoxActive" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ComboBoxInactive" />
</selector>
```

what state should I add for when it is displaying the dropdown? I want it to display ComboBoxActive drawable. I already tried adding this:

```
  <item android:state_enabled ="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ComboBoxActive"/>
```

Any idea of what the state is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no android:state_dropdown_showing state.
The only one state on spinner dropdown list is state_enabled="true"

You can use my selector to differentiate dropdown list state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- disabled state -->
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_off"/>
<!-- pressed state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pressed"/>
<!-- unselected state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default"/>
<!-- dropdown list state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_dropdown_list_is_shown"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default"/>
</selector>
```

Don't forget to set setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode properties on spinner.

Comment: If you add setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode you have to tap twice on the spinner (first = focus, second open dropdown). Have you the same issue ?

Comment: I have found a solution: I have attach a `focusChangeListener` and I `performClick` on the item click

Comment: The described solution doesnt work, backgrounds dont change when spinner dropdown is showing...

Answer (score 3):

Based on Olef Koshkin answer I can add that if you want save changed state after click to spinner and return it to default only after close spinner you can use. It works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- disabled state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_spinner_inactive"
          android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <!-- pressed state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_spinner_inactive"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <!-- unselected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_spinner_inactive"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <!-- dropdown list state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_spinner_inactive"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:state_focused="true"/>
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_spinner_active"/>
</selector>
```

In other cases I see blink of default state and I didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me**

> **This Selector is only for single spinner,In case of multiple spinner this selector will change all spinner's background bcoz we are using `state_window_focused` **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- For DropDown is Not Visible -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_bg_with_arrow_border_theme_color" android:state_window_focused="false"  />

<!-- For DropDown is enter code here Visible -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_bg_with_arrow_border" android:state_window_focused="true"  />
</selector>
```